# Insert into src_ table from dest_table without duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have two table, src_table and dest_table
src_table contain multiple rows including duplicates 
I want to copy rows from src_table to dest_table without duplicates.

please help me for it

Comment: @all what is the filter condition is there is duplicate? which one should pick?

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (column1,column2,column3,...)
SELECT DISTINCT column1,column2,column3,...
FROM src_table
```

Just use INSERT INTO ... SELECT DISTINCT. This will only select the distinct values. If you want to copy all columns, just remove the columns from the INSERT line and add a asterisk (*) to the SELECT. Beware of primary keys, distinct only works if the selected rows are 100% duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

By without duplicates do you also mean without duplicating values in the destination table?

If yes, you could always do a `LEFT JOIN` onto it for your `SELECT` query where a column `IS NULL`.

```
INSERT INTO dest_table ( column1, column2, column3, ... )
    SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, column3, ...
    FROM src_table a
    LEFT JOIN dest_table b ON a.column1 = b.column1 AND a.column2 = b.column2
              a.column3 = b.column3 ...
    WHERE b.column1 IS NULL
```

Basically it'll look for where the match fails and only insert those records.

Answer (score 0):

For example use this query:

```
create table #T1 (field1 int, field2 int)

insert #T1 values (1,2)
insert #T1 values (1,3)
insert #T1 values (2,1)

create table #T2 (field1 int, field2 int)

insert #T2 values (1,3) /*exists in first table*/
insert #T2 values (1,4) 
insert #T2 values (1,4) /*dublicated*/
insert #T2 values (2,2)

insert #T1
select distinct field1, field2 from #T2
where not exists (select 1 from #T1 where #T1.field1 = #T2.field1 and #T1.field2 = #T2.field2)

select * from #T1
```

Also in t-sql exists very useful MERGE statement...

Best regards,
Max